# How to delete coloring sequences from string in bash?

Tags: bash, terminal

How I should delete all color-controlling sequences (or even all unprintable sequences) from string in Bash?

For example, I have got a string with color swithcers:

```
a="\e[0;31m->\e0m"
```

If i will echo it like

```
echo -e "$a"
```

there will be printed two colored characters `->` - the string i want to get without any color.

In my actual situation, I am getting colored string building in script, so I can't just hardcode the result as a constant and I don't want to double the size of script to build both colored and uncolored results.

If answer will delete all escape-sequences, not only coloring ones, it will be okay. String can contain Unicode.

Comment: Consider to change your software design.

Comment: @Cyrus That would be a very good piece of advice for a software, but not for my shell config in 20-30 lines, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ a="\e[0;31m->\e0m"
$ echo $a | sed 's/\\e[^m]*m//g'
->
```

Something like this?

Comment: Oh, I was too tired while asking this question. Obviously, Yes!